# When sites have submission boxes for sending them an email are the emails server side or client side?

Tags: javascript, html, email, debugging

The question is pretty much the whole thing. I am just curious if the debugger for example can access the emails that a submit box will send them too?

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question - but emails can only be sent from a server, there's no way to send an email from the client-side.

Comment: Ah, I prolly didn't explain it that well. I was just looking to extract emails from sites as a project and wondering if was a way to extract which email those question forms are sending too.

Comment: It would be server side. Server as to know where emails are *always* so keeping it on client side doesn't make sense. Client side can be changed at anytime.

Comment: @Syfer thats what I thought. Thanks for confirming